# SIMPLE MVC Question MVC Redirect

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a controller that creates a news article. I want to redirect the user to the article's page, something like: "/article/1". Normally I could just throw in return View("MyAction") but I need to pass the integer along in this case. There are overloads for adding a model to the View method call but I don't see anything that will let me accomplish my goal.

What's the best way to do this?

Also, I used ViewData for my success message... if I use a redirect message it isn't going to function so is there a better way to do that too?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you might be looking for.

```
RedirectToAction(new {controller="controllerName", action="article", id=1});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it actually looks like this:return RedirectToAction("Article", new { id = newAnnouncement.AnnouncementId }); but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!